# Xpage REST service control and service bean

Tags: rest, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to implement REST Service using XPage REST Service Control. I have opted for "customRESTService".

I would like to emit JSON when this service is requested. I can write logic in Server Side Java Script.

But I noticed that this customRESTService also supports "serviceBean", meaning I can write whole logic in pure JAVA.

I have given below code of the bean. I have declared it in faces-config.xml as well. But it throws exception while rendering. Has anyone used "serviceBean" in customRESTService?

I appreciate any help!! Thanks!!

```
public class GetApproverJSON{
public GetApproverJSON(){
    System.out.println("Instantiating Bean");
}   

public String doGet() throws NotesException{

    JSONObject mainObj  = new JSONObject();;
    JSONObject itemObj;

    try{
        mainObj.put("label", "name");
        mainObj.put("identifier", "abbr");

        itemObj = new JSONObject();
        itemObj.put("name", "");
        itemObj.put("abbr", "");

        mainObj.accumulate("items", itemObj);

        return mainObj.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception occured while generating JSON ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return mainObj.toString();
    }finally{

    }
}
```

Error :

```
com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceException: Error while rendering service
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomService$ScriptServiceEngine.renderService(CustomService.java:304)
at com.ibm.domino.services.HttpServiceEngine.processRequest(HttpServiceEngine.java:167)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService._processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:252)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService.processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:229)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx.renderAjaxPartialLifecycle(AjaxUtilEx.java:206)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.renderAjaxPartial(FacesServletEx.java:221)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:166)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1267)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1251)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
      Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Bean getApproverJSON is not a CustomServiceBean
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomService.findBeanInstance(CustomService.java:226)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomService$ScriptServiceEngine.renderService(CustomService.java:255)
... 20 more
```

Comment: how does the declaration in the faces-config.xml of this class looks like. Can you provide the code??

Comment: Has this ever been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to:

```
public class GetApproverJSON{ ...}
```

to:

```
public class GetApproverJSON extends CustomServiceBean { 

   @Override
   public void renderService(CustomService service, RestServiceEngine engine) throws ServiceException {
        HttpServletRequest request = engine.getHttpRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = engine.getHttpResponse();

        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        // Here goes your code, get the response writer or stream

    }
```

since that's the interface the REST service is expecting. You will need to implement just `renderService`. You can get the method (GET, POST etc.) from the request object

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the service bean before, I usually create my own parser with a static doGet method very similar to yours and in the doGet property of the custom REST service make a call to the static doGet method I create. But I think (I'm probably wrong on this count) if you use the service bean it has to be an entire servlet like if you wrote your own actual REST Service, and not just the parser portion.

I've created quite a few of the parsers and have found that a list of maps:

List>

is usually the best approach for building the initial data. I then loop through the list to build my JSON. In the Extension Library there is a class called JsonWriter which makes it very easy to build a JSON Object. Use the JsonWriter like:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter jw = new JsonWriter(sw);
jw.startObject();
jw.startProperty("SomeProperty");
jw.outStringLiteral("SomeValue");
jw.endProperty();
jw.endObject();
return sw.toString();
```

For a full on example you can take a look at the [REST service I built for my JQuery FullCalendar demo](https://bitbucket.org/kstrickland/keithstric.com-demos/src/bed7e734e556/JQueryFullCalendar/Code/Java/com/keithstric/demo/rest/EventParser.java?at=master). While none of the methods are static (I need to track a couple of properties) you should get the basic idea. But what kicks the whole thing off is a call to the writeJson() method. That is invoked in [this custom control](https://bitbucket.org/kstrickland/keithstric.com-demos/src/bed7e734e556/JQueryFullCalendar/CustomControls/ccRestCalendar.xsp?at=master).

Those examples should get you going on building your own custom JSON parser and emitting that JSON back to your application.